# Dired heading directory with text-properties to jump to parent directories

Tags: dired, breadcrumbs

Speedbar has a nice feature wherein the directory heading at the top of a files/directory buffer contains various text properties for the user to jump to any of the parent directories by placing the cursor on the corresponding name and pressing the enter key.  I took it one step further and placed a text property at `point-min` to jump to root.

**Q**:   Is there an existing modification for `dired-mode` that accomplishes the same thing?  If not, then this thread can be used to create such a new feature.

**GOAL -- `dired-mode`**:  For example, the heading directory in `dired-mode` is:  `/Users/HOME/data/emacs/lisp`

- Placing the cursor at `point-min` and pressing enter will open a `dired` buffer at `/`
- Placing the cursor anywhere on the word `Users` and pressing enter will open a `dired` buffer at `/Users`
- Placing the cursor anywhere on the word `HOME` and pressing enter will open a `dired` buffer at `/Users/HOME`.
- Placing the cursor anywhere on the word `data` and pressing enter will open a `dired` buffer at `/Users/HOME/data`.
- Placing the cursor anywhere on the word `emacs` and pressing enter will open a `dired` buffer at `/Users/HOME/data/emacs`.

Comment: Sounds like you are describing breadcrumbs. This does not exist in vanilla Dired. And as far as I know, it does not yet exist in a Dired extension library.  It might exist in a Dired alternative (e.g. Midnight Commander or some such). I added this feature to Emacs Info several years back. It might be worthwhile to add it to Dired too. Perhaps you will be the first to do so. ;-)

Comment: I meant that I added it (optionally) to the mode line in [Info+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InfoPlus), not to Emacs. I added breadcrumbs to Emacs at the top of the Info buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added a similar feature to [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) ([`dired+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el)).

Turn on minor mode `diredp-breadcrumbs-in-header-line-mode`.

This puts breadcrumbs on a separate optional header line for the whole Dired buffer, not on each directory header (e.g. each inserted subdir).  If you prefer the latter then see [lawlist's approach](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13380/105).

If you want to turn it on automatically in all Dired buffers, you can do this:

```el
(add-hook 'dired-before-readin-hook 'diredp-breadcrumbs-in-header-line-mode)
```

---

This is the code I use:

```el
(define-minor-mode diredp-breadcrumbs-in-header-line-mode
    "Toggle the use of breadcrumbs in Dired header line.
    With arg, show breadcrumbs iff arg is positive."
  :init-value nil :group 'header-line :group 'Dired-Plus
  (unless (derived-mode-p 'dired-mode)
    (error "You must be in Dired or a mode derived from it to use this command"))
  (if diredp-breadcrumbs-in-header-line-mode
      (diredp-set-header-line-breadcrumbs)
    (setq header-line-format  (default-value 'header-line-format))))

(defun diredp-set-header-line-breadcrumbs ()
  "Show a header line with breadcrumbs to parent directories."
  (let ((parent  (diredp-parent-dir default-directory))
        (crumbs  ())
        (text    ""))
    (while parent
      (push parent crumbs)
      (setq parent  (diredp-parent-dir parent)))
    (dolist (dir  crumbs)
      (let ((crumbs-map  (make-sparse-keymap))
            (menu-map    (make-sparse-keymap "Breadcrumbs in Header Line")))
        (when dir
          (setq dir  (propertize
                      dir
                      'local-map
                      (progn (define-key crumbs-map [header-line mouse-1]
                               `(lambda () (interactive)
                                   (dired ,dir dired-actual-switches)))
                             (define-key crumbs-map [header-line mouse-2]
                               `(lambda () (interactive)
                                   (dired-other-window ,dir dired-actual-switches)))
                             crumbs-map)
                      'mouse-face 'mode-line-highlight
                      'help-echo "mouse-1: Dired; mouse-2: Dired in other window"))
          (setq text  (concat text (if (diredp-root-directory-p dir) "" "  ") dir)))
        (make-local-variable 'header-line-format)
        (setq header-line-format  text)))))
```

Comment: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/dired%2b.el hasn't yet been synchronized with http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dired%2b.el

Comment: I must have had a cached version -- it's in sync now.  :)  I lightly tested the new feature and everything appears to work as advertised.

Answer (score 2):

```lisp
(require 'dired)

(defface dired-mouseover-face
  '((t (:foreground "green")))
  "Face for `dired-mouseover-face'."
  :group 'dired)

(defvar dired-mouse-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [mouse-2] 'dired-follow-link)
    (define-key map [return] 'dired-follow-link)
    (define-key map [follow-link] 'mouse-face)
      map)
  "Keymap for mouse when in `dired-mode'.")

;; Author:  Drew Adams -- http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13411/2287
(defun dired-follow-link (event)
"Follow the link in the dired directory heading, causing a new
dired buffer to be opened."
  (interactive (list last-nonmenu-event))
  (run-hooks 'mouse-leave-buffer-hook)
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (posn-window (event-start event)))
    (let ((path  (get-text-property (posn-point (event-start event)) 'breadcrumb)))
      (dired path))))

(defun dired-propertize-directory-heading ()
(interactive)
  (unless (buffer-narrowed-p)
    (let* (
        p beg end path peol
        (inhibit-read-only t) )
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-min))
        (setq peol (point-at-eol))
        (set-text-properties (point) peol nil)
        (re-search-forward "\\([^/\\]+\\)[/\\]" peol t)
        (when (looking-back "\\(^ +\\)\\([a-zA-Z]:\\)?/")
          (setq p (match-end 1))
          (setq path (if (match-string 2) (concat (match-string 2) "/") "/"))
          (add-text-properties (point-min) (1- (match-end 0)) (list
            'breadcrumb path
            'mouse-face 'dired-mouseover-face
            'help-echo (format "mouse-2, RET: Follow the link to \"%s\"." path)
            'keymap dired-mouse-map)))
        (while (re-search-forward "\\([^/\\]+\\)[/\\]" peol t)
          (setq beg (match-beginning 1))
          (setq end (match-end 1))
          (setq path (buffer-substring-no-properties p end))
          (add-text-properties beg end (list
            'breadcrumb path
            'mouse-face 'dired-mouseover-face
            'help-echo (format "mouse-2, RET: Follow the link to \"%s\"." path)
            'keymap dired-mouse-map)))
        (setq path (buffer-substring-no-properties p (1- peol)))
        (add-text-properties (point) (1- peol) (list
          'breadcrumb path
          'mouse-face 'dired-mouseover-face
          'help-echo (format "mouse-2, RET: Follow the link to \"%s\"." path)
          'keymap dired-mouse-map))))))

(add-hook 'dired-after-readin-hook 'dired-propertize-directory-heading)
```

---

[image: Example]

Comment: Nice -- this is very handy.

Comment: @glucas -- thanks for trying it out -- as I use it more in different situations, I will revise the regexp as needed -- e.g., remote servers and such (with tramp) haven't been tested yet and I primarily use OSX, with just an occasional use of Emacs for Window.  At some point, I'll test it with dired+ and revise as needed for compatability.

Comment: Cool. For what it's worth I'm trying this out on Windows, but have only done normal / local dir stuff so far.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach to achieve the same thing. I've got this in use for a while now. To use it press <kbd>mouse-2</kbd> on the directory name.

```el
(require 'dired+)

(defadvice diredp-mouse-find-file-reuse-dir-buffer (before breadcrumb activate)
    (let (file)
    (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (posn-window (event-end event)))
      (save-excursion
    (goto-char (posn-point (event-end event)))
    (when (and (= (line-beginning-position) 1)
           (null (and (looking-back "^[[:blank:]]*") (= (char-after) ?/)))
           (search-forward-regexp "[/:]" (line-end-position) 'noErr))
      (search-backward-regexp "^[[:blank:]]*\\(.*\\).")
      (setq file (match-string-no-properties 1))
      (if (file-directory-p file)
          (progn
        (find-alternate-file (file-name-sans-versions file t))
        (deactivate-mark))
        (error "First line in dired buffer is no dir. I am confused.")
        ))))))
```

I know that this is hacky. But, it works for me.

If you do not want to require `dired+` advice `dired-mouse-find-file-other-window` instead.

Comment: Thank you for the mouse idea -- I've incorporated a variation of that idea into an alternative answer that uses text properties -- greatly appreciated.