# Debugging / understanding placement of keymap with text-properties

Tags: text-properties, mouse

**Q**:   Why does there appear to be a `keymap` on the hyphen of **hello-world** in the following example?

**GOAL**:  Place text properties before the hyphen and after the hyphen -- **without** any keymap being placed on the hyphen itself.

**Background**:  The following example has been constructed to place text properties only on the word "**hello**" and the word "**world**".  As far as I can tell, the hyphen between "**hello**" and "**world**" should *not* have any text properties.  Yet when I place the cursor at the hyphen and type `M-x describe-key RET RET`, I see that it is linked to `my-follow-link` from `my-mouse-map`.

```lisp
(defvar my-mouse-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [mouse-2] 'my-follow-link)
    (define-key map [return] 'my-follow-link)
    (define-key map [follow-link] 'mouse-face)
      map)
  "Keymap for mouse when in `my-mode'.")

;; Author:  Drew Adams -- http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13411/2287
;; Modified by @lawlist for purposes of testing different scenarios.
(defun my-follow-link (event)
"Doc-string."
(interactive (list last-nonmenu-event))
  (run-hooks 'mouse-leave-buffer-hook)
  (with-current-buffer (window-buffer (posn-window (event-start event)))
    (let ((foo  (get-text-property (posn-point (event-start event)) 'test)))
      (message "%s" foo))))

(defun test ()
(interactive)
  (fundamental-mode)
  (let* (beg end)
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (setq beg (point))
      (insert "hello")
      (setq end (point))
      (add-text-properties beg end (list
          'test "This is my first half of the test."
          'face '(:foreground "cyan" :weight bold)
          'mouse-face '(:foreground "red" :weight bold)
          'help-echo "mouse-2, RET:  My first message."
          'keymap my-mouse-map))
      (insert "-")
      (setq beg (point))
      (insert "world")
      (setq end (point))
      (add-text-properties beg end (list
          'test "This is my seond half of the test."
          'face '(:foreground "orange" :weight bold)
          'mouse-face '(:foreground "blue" :weight bold)
          'help-echo "mouse-2, RET:  My second message."
          'keymap my-mouse-map)))))
```

---

[image: Example]
[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. I did `M-x test` in a new buffer, and saw `hello-world` got inserted. There are no text properties on the hyphen.

Perhaps you are not showing all your code or describing the context from the beginning.

And why are you using `describe-key`? And what key do you hit after `RET` - that key will be described.

Try `C-u C-x =` instead, with point before the hyphen.

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this thread.  Even though there are no text properties on the hyphen, pressing the return key on the hyphen is triggering the function `my-follow-link`.  As far as I can tell it should not be triggering that function, yet it is.  All of the code is included.  The second screen shot was made using `C-u C-x =` -- it shows there are no text properties, yet Emacs treats that point as having a keymap at that location.  Perhaps there is something wrong (a bug?) with `follow-link` internally that looks at the preceding or subsequent point?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect that my testing included:  `M-x describe-key RET RET`

Comment: Looks like a bug, to me. Same thing is true if you insert a char after `world` and you hit `RET` before that char (but not if you insert another and hit `RET` before it). `insert` is supposed not to have properties inherit, so rear stickiness should not be a problem. Unless someone gives you a good explanation, consider reporting this as a bug.

Comment: The same is true in Emacs 22, BTW. Perhaps this is intentional, but in that case the doc should mention it (e.g. specifically for any properties such as `keymap` that it applies to).

Comment: A workaround may be to place a dummy keymap at that location -- e.g., `(put-text-property (point) (1+ (point)) 'keymap 'dummy)` -- so that the buffer default (global or buffer-local keymaps) work again.